# PHP display each column of a row of Mysql results in session variables - next row on refresh

Tags: php, mysql, session

okay,

going crazy here - i wanted to display each row of a array (from results of Mysql query) one at a time. i had them in while loop and all rows showed at once. i was then advised to ditch the while loop and use sessions.

i have spent hours trying to get this to work - using comments on this site and PHP tutorials, but am very confused and need help.

scenario:

eg. Mysql query:
select col1, col2, col3, col4 from MyTable.  (MyTable has about 10 rows)

> display
>
> col1 (row1)
>
> col2 (row1)
>
> col3 (row1)
>
> col4 (row1)
>
> refresh browser (or pref - click Submit button)
>
> display
>
> col1 (row2)
>
> col2 (row2)
>
> col3 (row2)
>
> col4 (row2)

refresh/submit .... etc etc until all rows have been displayed.

i believe i have to use `$_SESSION` variables - i tried - in each refresh - to set the variables like this

```
$_SESSION['column1']= $rownum;

$_SESSION['column2']= $rownum;

$_SESSION['column3']= $rownum;

$_SESSION['column4']= $rownum;
```

but i don't get the columns displaying correctly.

please help me resolve this - and if possible with code example - including the session start and refresh or whatever it may need.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add `session_start();` before using sessions

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['pop'] = 12;
echo $_SESSION['pop'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's couple ways how you can do this.

First is being mysql offset (not getting all rows but needed part (you might have 10000 rows there - all at once will be problem)).

First example can be used if you have quite some records or you want to prepare for future as it can handle large record groups.

Second example can be used if you have small group of records or you do sort of caching of database pre-script execution.

Example #1:

MySql -

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM MyTable LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

php -

```
session_start();

$position = isset($_SESSION['display_position']) ? $_SESSION['display_position'] : 0;
$limit    = 4;

if(empty($position))
    $_SESSION['display_position'] = 0;

$sql    = 'SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM MyTable LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$position;
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// We don't want to fetch non existen resource
if($result)
{
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $rows;
    }   
}
else
{
    echo 'No more records';
    exit;
}

// Update session for next run
$_SESSION['display_position'] = $position + $limit;
```

Other would be for example array looping and storing position in $_SESSION.

Example #2:

Mysql -

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM MyTable
```

php -

```
session_start();

$records = array('row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'row5', 'row6', 'row7', 'row8', 'row9', 'row10');

$position = isset($_SESSION['display_position']) ? $_SESSION['display_position'] : 0;
$limit    = 4;

if(empty($position))
    $_SESSION['display_position'] = 0;

if(count($records) < $position)
{
    echo 'No more records';
    exit;
}

for($i = $position; $i < $position + $limit; $i++)
{
    // Display rows
    if(isset($records[$i]))
        echo $records[$i];
}

// Update session for next run
$_SESSION['display_position'] = $position + $limit;
```

Note: Adjust `$limit` variable to suit your needs.

Your specific use case (**updated**):

```
session_start();

$records = array(
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow1',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow1',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow1',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow1'
    ),
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow2',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow2',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow2',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow2'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow3',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow3',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow3',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow3'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow4',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow4',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow4',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow4'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow5',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow5',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow5',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow5'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow6',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow6',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow6',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow6'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow7',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow7',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow7',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow7'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow8',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow8',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow8',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow8'
    ), 
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow9',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow9',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow9',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow9'
    ),
    array(
        'col1' => 'col1valuerow10',
        'col2' => 'col2valuerow10',
        'col3' => 'col3valuerow10',
        'col4' => 'col4valuerow10'
    )
);

$position = isset($_SESSION['display_position']) ? $_SESSION['display_position'] : 0;
$limit    = 1;

if(empty($position))
    $_SESSION['display_position'] = 0;

if(count($records) < $position)
{
    echo 'No more records';
    exit;
}

for($i = $position; $i < $position + $limit; $i++)
{
    // Display rows
    if(isset($records[$i])){
        echo $records[$i]['col1'] . '<br/>';
        echo $records[$i]['col2'] . '<br/>';
        echo $records[$i]['col3'] . '<br/>';
        echo $records[$i]['col4'] . '<br/>';
    }
}

// Update session for next run
$_SESSION['display_position'] = $position + $limit;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I'm so confused - i posted a query previously regarding displaying my array using a 'while' and wanting to delay the display until i'd clicked "next" or something, but people told me i shouldn't use a while loop (or foreach i guess) and should use session variables instead ... but these answers on the page seem to use a while or array loop.    i must say this whole PHP thing is quite confusing !?!?!?!

Comment: @apetersen21 hey, i understand your confusion. The thing is in php you work with database records using while loops, you can build array also from within of while loop and use that.

For stop until next is clicked that would be the fronted technique right there using ajax and DOM manipulation.

What are your concerns in my code? What's not working for you? Is that what you not intended to get?

Comment: hi @arma. i don't have an issue with your code, i'm going to try applying it to my actual code now. its just that i was happy to use a while loop as it made sense to me, but when i posted a query about halting the while loop between each row (until a button is clicked) i was told to ditch the while loop and use sessions instead. i guess everyone has different ways of doing things - i just need to find what works for me i guess. and while loops DO work for me!   i am so new to web development its a massive learning curve for me. give me old-school programming anyday !!

Comment: right - i have just copy/pasted your second example and this is definitely something to work from. thankyou.  will be back if i get stuck on displaying more than one field (ie. your example has a single array set ... my code puts the results of a query into an array so each row has columns too.

Comment: @apetersen21 take a look @ updated 3rd example. It shows more live like data you might get.

Comment: Thanks again @arma - i experimented quite a bit last night and am now able to display each row of sql output - and separate the fields appropriately. My next step is to get my "Next" button to call the next row and refreshing the screen should not move the array on. - as i say its all a learning curve and once i get over one hurdle i'm heading for the next. best way to learn i'd say.

Comment: @apetersen21 i'm glad that it worked out for you. I quite didn't understand what you mean by "should not move the array on". But next button is easy in current setup, just make button that redirect to the current page and that's it.

Comment: Thanks @arma, i shall try this later this evening. What I meant by 'not move array on' is that i want to be able to refresh the webpage, but it needs to return the current row of the table again and not move on to the next one until i click the NEXT button. i will probably have a PREVIOUS button as well once i have mastered the NEXT functionality.

Comment: ... and bottom line is - i am trying to teach myself web development (PHP & MySQL) at the same time as doing a course in animal anatomy (?!), so i thought i'd develop a PHP/MySql application that i can also use to test my knowledge (multiple choice test) on the other subject too. I have plenty DB experience and am storing all the anatomy info in tables "kill 2 birds with one stone" as they say.

Answer (score 0):

Add a primary key column to your table if you don't already have one.  You can then use the following:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_SESSION["id"] + 1;
}
else{
    $_SESSION["id"] = 1;
}

$id = $_SESSION["id"];

//Your mysql connection 

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM urtable 
                        WHERE id = $id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    echo $row["urcol1"];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row["urcol2"];
    echo "<br><br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks - a combination of @arma's and your solution is getting me where i'm trying to go.